# How to let a button open a link

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I just put a button and I don't know how to assign things to it.
I mean like I click the button the another link is opened.

My button code

```
<input type="button" value="anything">
```

Comment: ...your button code?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight sry i am putting it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow please read this before posting a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply make a button link to another website/ page, here you go:

```
<button onclick="location.href='link_goes_here'" type="button">
 Button_Text_Here</button>
```

> note the different quotation marks being used :)
>
> edit:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='link_goes_here'" value="button_text>
```

Comment: Thx a lot thats ok

Comment: @YashrajSingh I've edited the code after you added yours. Check and accept if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like an `<a href="the_url_where_to_go">text</a>` then you format it with css like

```
a {
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

otherwise you can use the button with javascript

```
 <button onclick="location.href='the_url_where_to_go'" type="button">
 Button_Text_Here</button>
```

or

```
 <input type="button" onclick="location.href='the_url_where_to_go'" value="text_of_the button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```html
<button onclick="window.open('https://example.com')">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do

```html
<input type="button" value="Anything" onclick="window.location='http://www.example.org'" />
```

or

```html
<a href="http://www.example.org"><button>Anything</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `<a>` tag with a button inside. very simple.

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><button>Click this link</button></a>
```